# targetSdkVersion gradle strange value

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, targetsdkversion

So, I cloned this project from Github and while going through its `build.gradle`, I found this strange configuration, particularly for `targetSdkVersion`. Now, before I jump into the details of what it is, let me mention that the project has two modules - `app`(the main one) and `callrecord`(encapsualting the call recording functionality)

Here is the `build.gradle` file for the same:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion project.sdk

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aykuttasil.callrecorder"
        minSdkVersion project.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion project.sdk
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':callrecord')
}
```

Can you see it?

I don't understand the line `compileSdkVersion project.sdk`. This project "object" has been referenced at several other places too.

First, why would someone use this property? Second, how do I find out what version it is?

Comment: _why would someone use this property ?_  because changing it in one place will effect every where and all versions can be maintained at single place , _how do I find out what version it is?_  I am not sure but check project level `build.gradle`

Answer (score 4):

> why would someone use this property?

- The main purpose behind to use this property To Configure all variables for  Android project modules in one place
- so changing it in one place will effect in whole project

> how do I find out what version it is?

- it will be available in **`gradle.properties`**  or **`build.gradle`** in file

have a  look in  [**`Build.Gradle file of CallRecorder`**](https://github.com/aykuttasil/CallRecorder/blob/8703675bcbc1417e24d1c8a0dcdfcba336b2c197/build.gradle#L32) of that project

[image]

## **SAMPLE**

Here is the good article on it [**`Configure variables for all Android project modules in one place`**](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/gradle-configure-variables-for-all-android-project-modules-in-one-place-5a6e56cd384e)

> **`gradle.properties`**

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
android.useAndroidX = true
android.enableJetifier = false

#gradle.properties
myTargetSdkVersion=27
myCompileSdkVersion=27
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
```

[image]

> than use in your **`Build.Gradle`**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion project.myTargetSdkVersion.toInteger()
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nilesh.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion project.myMinSdkVersion.toInteger()
        targetSdkVersion project.myTargetSdkVersion.toInteger()
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}
```

Comment: I just checked `gradle.properties` and `settings.gradle`. I couldn't find the settings there.

Comment: @pulp_fiction can u share that github project link

Comment: @pulp_fiction check this link https://github.com/aykuttasil/CallRecorder/blob/8703675bcbc1417e24d1c8a0dcdfcba336b2c197/build.gradle#L32