# Properties with dot notation in gradle.build file

Tags: android, maven, gradle, build

To be consistent with my company standards I need to use dot notations in properties that I would like to define in a `gradle.build` file. 
I know I could define them in a `gradle.properties` file, but I was looking a way to define some of them in a gradle.build file expecially for testing, so I don't have to create 2 files every time for each functional test (`gradle.build` and `gradle.properties`). 
In `gradle.build` tried without success:

```
com {
  mycompany {
    project { 
        aproperty = false
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried without success:

```
com.mycompany.project.aproperty=false
```

Is there any workaround for setting properties with dot notation in `gradle.build`?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52108414/7666442

Comment: I've had a look in to it, but I don't see any dot notation in those properties. The name of the properties that I would like to set is like `com.mycompany.project.propertyname`

Comment: check again it using `project.myTargetSdkVersion.toInteger()` in `Build.Gradle`

Comment: `project.myTargetSdkVersion.toInteger()` it's a method invocation, while in my case I need to do something like `com.mycompany.project.propertyname='hello'`

Comment: also `org.gradle.jvmargs` is set in the properties file, not in `build.gradle`

Comment: you can use extraproperties:  set value with  `project.ext["com.mycompany.project.propertyname"] = "foo"`, then acces the value with `ext["com.mycompany.project.propertyname"]` .  But note that using dotted named properties is not recommanded in groovy/gradle as you will have to use specific syntax to set/access these.

Comment: you cannot set a property value in `build.gradle` in that way