# Where are implementation version string stored in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

In the app-level gradle file

```
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

Where can I find the kotlin_version value?

When I try to add the following dependency

```
implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:$billingVersion"
```

Error: `Could not get unknown property 'billingVersion' for object of type`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52108414/7666442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These can usually be found in your root `build.gradle` file as they are variables defined for all modules of your app. you can double-tap shift and type `build.gradle` to find the root version (it will show as `build.gradle(.)`)

as a super basic example, it will look something like this :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

you can also do cool stuff like this with root versions :

```
buildscript { 

ext.versions = [
        'appcompat'           : '1.1.0-rc01',
        'const_layout'        : '2.0.0-beta2',
        'arch_comp'           : '1.1.1',
        'kotlin'              : '1.3.50',
         ....
]
```

here, I'm defining an entire range of variables with their versions and then you can simply reference these with :

`$versions.appcompat` as you need them (as an example)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

you can find it in project level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
```

you can define your version  variables in same as

```
ext {

    minSdkVersion = 16
    targetSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 27
    buildToolsVersion = '27.0.3'
}
```